# Emailing multiple data tables in outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently repurposing this code I found online so that I can send multiple data tables in one email body. I would also like to have a textual email body as well. When I try to include a text body (.body) it is later replaced with the table (.htmlbody). I assume then if I try to place another table in the email as well, it will replace the 1st table with the 2nd. Is there a way to place multiple bodies within an outlook email using markers or something. I have done this before in Microsoft word but not sure how to go about it in outlook.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:F5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
    .display
    .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .body = "Here is the email body"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    '.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: just a stab in the dark but perhaps a couple of html line breaks between each table would do the trick? Something like: `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) + "<br /><br />" + RangetoHTML(rng2)`?

Comment: Another possibility would be to make each range an attachment.  You cannot split the body into parts using markers because that functionality is already used to handle attachments.  Warning: `RangeToHtml` creates poor Html that uses pixel widths.  Apparently PC browsers can cope but at least some smartphone browsers cannot.

Comment: Another possibility is to convert the ranges to Html with VBA.  This can be reasonably fast providing the formatting within the range is not too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of how the `.body` and `.HTMLBody` properties work is that they both assign a value to the body of the email, replacing anothing that's already there. `.body` expects regular text while `.HTMLBody` expects information in HTML form.

To get it to not replace the text you're inserting into `.body`, when you assign `.HTMLBody`, try `.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br /><br />" & RangetoHTML(rng)`

(This has worked for me, when appending an HTML signature to an email message, although I have used `"<p><BR/><BR/></p>"` as the line break for that.)

That line should also work when adding any other additional information, because it's taking what is currently in the body of the email and appending on the new information after a linebreak before reassigning the resulting string to the `.HTMLBody` (HTML linebreak syntax courtesy of [Glitch_Docter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6387479/glitch-doctor) comment on the question).

Comment: I have not looked at `RangeToHml` for some years because the output was too poor for my purposes.  My recollection was that the output was a complete Html document including a header and a body. Have you or @Glitch_Doctor checked that Outlook's browsers can handle concatenated Html documents?

Comment: This was why I only offered up a comment, without actually testing it I can't be sure it'd work and I am too busy to knock up another Ron de Bruin test case right now :)

Comment: @TonyDallimore, @Glitch_Docter  I just tested his `RangeToHTML` function, and it returns a `Variant/String`. I successfully appended it to an email body (along with an HTML signature), so it works fine for Excel 2016. I did add a linebreak syntax variation to what I have saved from using previously.